# can't checkout or update from NO SVN repository

Tags: svn

I started having these problems after arriving in the UK. Regardless of the network I connect to, regardless of the repository I try to get code from, I always get this:

```
svn: OPTIONS of '{{REPO_URL_HERE}}': Could not read status line: connection was closed by server ({{REPO_URL_HERE}})
```

When opening the URL in the browser though, I get a directory listing. It's like GETs are processed ok, but OPTIONs are not. I tried with setting DNS to 8.8.8.8, deleting `~/.subversion`, nothing changes. It works over svn+ssh though. 
I'm on OS X 10.8. I don't remember doing anything in particular related to the Subversion installation or config.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question to my Facebook wall, a non-tech friend of mine posted a random google result, which, amazingly enough, had the solution. And there is a dozen of similar questions, and they all have a logical solution, whereas this one is just ridiculous:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613149/svn-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-server/14225362#14225362